# Using linux environment variable in rsyslog template

Tags: ubuntu, logging, log-files, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to add an environment variable to my rsyslog template.
I tried using 'getenv()' function without any luck, I always get an empty string in return.

I'm attaching an example of my rsyslog config file, I'm using 'HOME' env variable as an example.

#### /etc/rsyslog.d/00-my_log.conf

```
set $.my_home=getenv("HOME");

template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\",\"my_home\":\"")     property(name="$.my_home")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}

*.* action(type="omfile" dirCreateMode="0700" FileCreateMode="0644"
       template="json-template" File="/var/log/my_log")
```

#### /var/log/my_log

```
{"my_home":"","message":"my log message"}
```

**rsyslogd**: version 8.4.2

Comment: This works for me, but I have version 8.30.0. If you run `rsyslogd -dn`  you will get lots of debug output. There might be an error message about getenv in there. For a normal input line I see in the debug: `SET .my_home = function 'getenv' ... string 'HOME' `END SET`

Comment: Sadly I can't easily update my rsyslog version, it will require me to compile rsyslog and its dependencies to my specific Debian armv7l distribution.
With `rsyslogd -dn`, I can see the line you mentioned, it actually defines to variable 3 times but in the end it's still an empty string. Anyway, I'll just find a workaround as this issue doesn't worth getting into a compilation session. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was able to use this guidance
[rsyslog: Specify `action` parameters from environment variables](https://serverfault.com/questions/979959/rsyslog-specify-action-parameters-from-environment-variables)

to shell out from the config file to get the environment variables in the template:

```
template(name="logfile" type="list") {
   constant(value="{")

   constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     
   property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="rfc3339")
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_namespace\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_POD_NAMESPACE`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_name\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_POD_NAME`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_ip\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_INSTANCE_ADDR`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   property(name="$!all-json" position.from="2")
}
```