# rsyslog: Specify `action` parameters from environment variables

Tags: logging, rsyslog, elasticsearch

I'm using rsyslog to send logs to elasticsearch. It all works well in my local environment, but now I'm trying to make it more generic and inject environment variables where needed.

As part of my rsyslog.conf is this omelasticsearch action:

```
action(
    type="omelasticsearch"
    server=<somehow use $ES_HOST here>
    template="haproxy"
    bulkmode="on"
    searchIndex="haproxy-index"
    dynSearchIndex="on"
    usehttps="on"
    asyncrepl="on"
    uid=<somehow use $ES_USER here>
    pwd=<somehow use $ES_PASSWORD here>
)
```

I tried using `getenv()` and setting variables, but I couldn't find a way to inject said variable into the parameters of my action.

Did I miss something simple, or is that just not doable?

Comment: You should be able to use `getenv()` where a string is required. Please add to your post how you are using it.

Comment: I tried that, but you can't use a function in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can shell out from the config file by using backticks.

```
action(
    type="omelasticsearch"
    server=`echo $ES_HOST`
    template="haproxy"
    bulkmode="on"
    searchIndex="haproxy-index"
    dynSearchIndex="on"
    usehttps="on"
    uid=`echo $ES_USER`
    pwd=`echo $ES_PASSWORD`
)
```

Comment: i am so very grateful for your suggestion !!!  works for templates too

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this technique in the rsyslog template to pass properties to your elasticsearch index with environment variable values like this

```
template(name="logfile" type="list") {
   constant(value="{")

   constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     
   property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="rfc3339")
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_namespace\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_POD_NAMESPACE`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_name\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_POD_NAME`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   constant(value="\"pod_ip\":\"")     
   constant(value=`echo $KUB_INSTANCE_ADDR`)
   constant(value="\", ")
   
   property(name="$!all-json" position.from="2")
}
```